# stored procedure in temp table result not show aspnet mvc project

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asmx, temp

I am doing data display query service through asmx web service project

I have a stored procedure. This system in create temp table and result all datas. For example;

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;    
CREATE TABLE #tempdb (USERNAME nvarchar(100),DATES date,POINT int,DEGREE int,TOTAL int)
```

insert by this temp table;

```
INSERT INTO #tempdb VALUES ('serdar','2021-12-20',5,8,14)
```

at the bottom i delete this virtual table

```
SET NOCOUNT OFF; 
SET @sql = 'select USERNAME,DATES,POINT,DEGREE,TOTAL from #tempdb'
exec(@sql)    
DROP TABLE #tempdb
```

**NOTES: SQL Server in show all datas in temp table**

When I call this stored procedure structure in my aspnet mvc project, the result is int. My expectation is that it comes out as a list and that's why I can't even tolist.

The models folder doesn't even have a result value for this procedure.

asmx web service background code (this int result but want list):

```
[WebMethod]
        public int UserPoints(string username,DateTime start)
        {
            var results = database.tempProecudre(username, start);
            return results;
        }
```

What should I do?

Comment: *"When I call this stored procedure structure in my aspnet mvc project, the result is int."* This sounds like you're reading the `RETURN` value *not* the result set. But with no code from your application, impossible to truly know.

Comment: I added the web service code to the question, but as I said, there is no result for this procedure in models and not show tolist() methods

Comment: Not related to your problem but get rid of the NOLOCK hint. Absolutely unnecessary with temp tables and a bad practice with permanent tables too. Add your code for `database.tempProecudre`.

Comment: If you need to return a list then why have you declared `public int UserPoints(string username,DateTime start)` with an `int` return type?

Comment: database.tempProecudre(username, start).ToList(); not working and not seeing

Comment: normally the procedure should have a result.cs file and it doesn't exist

Comment: Show us the code for "database.tempProecudre".

Comment: Why are you now assigning your SQL statement to a variable and executing that? Such methodology is normally when you use dynamic SQL (though you have the bad habit of using the `EXEC (@SQL)` syntax), however, there is *nothing* dynamic about your statement.

Comment: exce(@sql) direct select ...... from #tempdb two method trying but not response

Comment: As @TomRegan said, show the code for `database.tempProecudre`.

Comment: You did not show us the code for "database.tempProecudre". You need to do that.

Comment: i solved. not using temp table, create new real table and stored procedure last operation firstly select all datas and after this table truncate

Comment: @DanGuzman why not using with(nolock) code, i wonding

Comment: @SerdarÇeliker, although `NOLOCK` (or `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level) is all too commonly used to avoid blocking, it may 1) return uncommitted data that was later rolled back or 2) skip or duplicate rows due to data movement. See [this](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/10/using-nolock-heres-how-youll-get-the-wrong-query-results/).  A better method to avoid blocking is with query/index tuning or a snapshot (row-versioning) isolation level.